# How to display database contents in a new activity at onclick of a button?

Tags: android, sqlite

thing is, if i click a button GETDATA - then a new activity starts new.java and i want it to display the contents of my database.
in this new.java i have strings name and id. and i have lined database and this class, such that name and id have the corresponding details that i want to display.

now the ques is, how to display them ?
if i have a

```
EditText ta;
ta=findViewBy(R.id.edittext1);
ta.setText(name);
```

should this work ?

it isnt working. also, i dont want user to change the contents and want to make this filed un-editable.
should i use

```
TextView tf; 
ta=findViewBy(R.id.textview1);
tf.setText(name);
```

?
even this isnt happening.
what is the procedure for this ?

Comment: `what is the procedure for this ?` you should start [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) and back after you go through all trainings

Comment: my database is created, and data is stored. i am even able to display that as a toast. But i want it to be displayed in an activity when i click a button for this

Answer (score 0):

it is done by using append.
    TextView ta;
    ta=(TextEdit)findViewById(Ri.id.textView1);
    String a=getData(1); // goto database, id is 1
    ta.append(a);